How to add inflows and outflows to Monte Carlo Model in Python
I am trying to simulate my portfolio's total value over time. Here is my current code:
'''
def monte_carlo_simulation(self, name="Portfolio", mc_sims=10000, years=23):
    
    # Extract the parameters
    expected_annual_return = self.geo_return  # 6.9% annualized expected return
    expected_monthly_return = self.expected_monthly_return
    expected_annual_volatility = self.expected_vol  # 16.19% annualized volatility
    expected_monthly_vol = self.expected_monthly_vol
    initial_portfolio_value = self.sma_value  # Initial portfolio value
    
    # Time and simulation settings
    T = 12 * years  # Total time horizon in months
    dt = 1/12 # Monthly Time Step
    N = T  # Number of time steps in months
    t = np.arange(1, int(N) + 1)  # Time points
    
    # Generate a date range starting from `start_date`, for the number of months in the simulation
    dates = pd.date_range(start=start_date, periods=int(N) + 1, freq='M')  # +1 to include the initial value
    
    # Monte Carlo parameters based on GBM
    mu = expected_monthly_return  # Use expected monthly return as drift (μ)
    sigma = expected_monthly_vol  # Use expected monthly volatility as diffusion (σ)
    
    # Generate Brownian motion for all scenarios
    b = {str(scen): np.random.normal(0, 1, int(N)) for scen in range(1, mc_sims + 1)}
    W = {str(scen): b[str(scen)].cumsum() * np.sqrt(dt) for scen in range(1, mc_sims + 1)}
    
    # Drift and diffusion components of the GBM
    drift = (mu - 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * t
    diffusion = {str(scen): sigma * W[str(scen)] for scen in range(1, mc_sims + 1)}
    
    # Simulate portfolio values using GBM for all simulations
    S = np.array([initial_portfolio_value * np.exp(drift + diffusion[str(scen)]) for scen in range(1, mc_sims + 1)])
    S = np.hstack((np.array([[initial_portfolio_value] for scen in range(mc_sims)]), S))  # Add initial value at the start

'''
From this code, I want to add an annual outflow, but i am honestly unsure on how to add it... I have tried to make the change to the line S = np.array([initial_portfolio_value * np.exp(drift + diffusion[str(scen)]) for scen in range(1, mc_sims + 1)]) that calculates the forecasted value to:
'''
    for scen in range(mc_sims):  # Loop through each simulation, zero-indexed
        for i in range(1, int(N) + 1):  # Loop through each time step, starting from 1
            # Generate a random normal value for Brownian motion (Z)
            Z = np.random.normal(0, 1)
            
            # Apply the GBM formula step-by-step
            S[scen, i] = S[scen, i - 1] * np.exp((mu - 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * dt + sigma * np.sqrt(dt) * Z)
            
            
            # Check if it's the 12th month (i.e., every year)
            if i % 12 == 0:
                # Subtract the outflow amount
                S[scen - 1, i] -= self.annuity_payment_share

'''
However, this is incorrect. Any help would be appreciated.
